# Add button on the screen without using MaterialApp Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make simple example that has a clickable button in center of screen in Flutter. I can do that using MaterialApp widget but I want to do it without using MaterialApp.

This example works with Text widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, world!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
  ) ;
}
```

But all my trials to change the Text widget with FlatButton or RaisedButton failed because they depend on Material Widget

I also tried that:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child:Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Press meh', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
          )
      )
  );
}
```

Question is: Is there any way to have Button that does not depend on Material Widget?

Comment: Like that ? import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
  Card(
    child: Center(
      child: FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, world!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
    )
  )
  );
}
not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use - `WidgetsApp` then.

```
void main() {
  runApp(SomeText());
}

class SomeText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetsApp(
      builder: (context, int) {
        return Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              'Hello, world!',
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}
```

As per Doc -

> [WidgetsApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp-class.html), which defines the basic app elements but does not depend
>   on the material library.

[image]

**Update -** Without Other Class:

If you use `home:` then you need to pass - `onGenerateRoute` or `pageRouteBuilder`

> If neither builder nor onGenerateRoute are provided, the
>   pageRouteBuilder must be specified so that the default handler will
>   know what kind of PageRoute transition to build.

```
void main() {
  runApp(WidgetsApp(
    builder: (context, int) {
      return Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(
            'Hello, world!',
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    color: Colors.blue,
  ));
}
```

Comment: Can we do it without separate class ? I mean I tried the following but I get an exception:
void main() {
  runApp(
      WidgetsApp(
        home: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'Hello, world!',
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              ),
            ),
        )
      )
  );
}

Comment: Thank you it works. But I don't understand why we need this part "
builder: (context, int) {
      return "
Because in the case of the Text, we did not need that.

Comment: because - This Widget has condition  - `'builder != null ||
         onGenerateRoute != null ||
        pageRouteBuilder != null':` so you have define any one of them to work.

Comment: i used `builder` simply